# Wrong returns the selected dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want select date

```
SELECT  [Dt]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[PayerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SaleCount]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[IsPromo]
      ,[CustomerType]
      ,[koef]
  FROM [Action].[dbo].[mytab1]
 where dt> 2018-06-27
 order by dt
```

as the result i get that

```
Dt
2017-10-12 00:00:00.000
2017-10-12 00:00:00.000
2017-10-12 00:00:00.000
2017-10-12 00:00:00.000
2017-10-13 00:00:00.000
2017-10-13 00:00:00.000
2017-10-13 00:00:00.000
2017-10-13 00:00:00.000
2017-10-14 00:00:00.000
2017-10-14 00:00:00.000
```

what's wrong? why query returns me all data and not that > 2018-06-27

Comment: Because your date literal should be a string. '20180627'. The way you have it is an int. Notice I also removed the dashes to use the ANSI compliant format YYYYMMDD

Comment: This SQL should be invalid. Don't know why SQL Server even accepts it.

Comment: @TheImpaler because SQL Server is quite happy to implicitly cast a numerical value to a `datetime`. `0` in a `datetime` is `19000101`. Note that this is **not** the case for `datetime2`, `date`, or `datetimeoffset`; you cannot implicitly (or explicitly) cast a numerica value to a `datetime2`, etc.

Comment: @Lamu - I hear you. But this behavior produces errors more often than not.

Comment: @TheImpaler that *might* be (one of the reasons) why they removed the behaviour with the new datatypes. *Also, RN, not M :)*

Answer (score 5):

The problem here, like Sean has said, is that you are using the Numerical expression `2018-06-27`, which evaluates to `1985`. If you convert `1985` to a `datetime` you get the value `1905-06-09 00:00:00.000`, thus your `WHERE` clause is effectively:

```
WHERE dt> '1905-06-09T00:00:00.000'
```

Like Sean also said, use a literal string, and an unambiguous format (these are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyyMMddThh:mm:ss.sss`. Thus your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE dt > '20180627'
```

Answer (score 2):

@D.Joe you need to change the date variable to be in single quote.

From:

```
SELECT  [Dt]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[PayerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SaleCount]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[IsPromo]
      ,[CustomerType]
      ,[koef]
  FROM [Action].[dbo].[mytab1]
 where dt> 2018-06-27
 order by dt
```

To:

```
SELECT  [Dt]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[PayerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[SaleCount]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[IsPromo]
      ,[CustomerType]
      ,[koef]
  FROM [Action].[dbo].[mytab1]
 where dt> '20180627'
 order by dt
```